# Get data against id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my Controller code to show order detail against order id. When press button to check detail order, I have successfully received id of order that comes from order page but does not receive after findL

```
public function detailorders($id){
   print_r($id); die;
   $this->dorders = orderdetail::find($id);

   $data = (array)$this;

   return view('template/admin/modules/orders/detailorders',compact('data'));
}
```

Here the code about show all details of order thats comes from order page agains order id

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">{{$data->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$data->order_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$data->product_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$data->price}}</td>
  <td>{{$data->subtotal}}</td>
  <td>{{$data->quantity}}</td>
```

`orderdetail` model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class orderdetail extends Model{

}
```

I am getting this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
>   (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping_cart\resources\views\template\admin\modules\orders\detailorders.blade.php)

Comment: I don't know laravel, _but_ you cast `$data` as _array_ here: `$data = (array)$this;`. As I said, I don't know how laravel processes that, but you could give `$data['id']` a try.

Comment: share route for `detailorders` ?

Comment: What you mean with `but does not receive after findL`. Please edit your question and perhaps still add a used controller-function if it could be helpful to answer your question. Perhaps this site is helping: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: route is ok i have passed id with route name like detailorder/{id}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not sending the correct thing to the view. See this line:

```
$data = (array)$this;
```

That means you're converting the Controller to an `array` and sending that to the view. You're getting the error since you can't use object access `->...` on an `array`, but that's not the whole issue. Fix your code to below:

```
public function detailorders($id){
  // Removed print_r() and die(); not needed here, and prevents execution.
  $dorder = orderdetail::findOrFail($id); // Changed to findOrFail; will thrown an error if unable to find record.

  return view('template/admin/modules/orders/detailorders',compact('dorder'));
}
```

Then, in your view file, simply reference as:

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class="sorting_1">{{$dorder->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$dorder->order_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$dorder->product_id}}</td>
  <td>{{$dorder->price}}</td>
  <td>{{$dorder->subtotal}}</td>
  <td>{{$dorder->quantity}}</td>
```

Edit: `findOrFail($id)` is checking for `where id = ?` in your `orderdetail` table. To fix this, use

```
$dorder = orderdetail::where("order_id", "=", $id)->firstOrFail();
```

This will check for `where order_id = ?` in your `orderdetail` table.

Comment: No query results for model [App\orderdetail] 51

Comment: Well, do you have a row in your `orders` table with an id of 51? Post your `orderdetail` model and migration for `orders` table.

Comment: yes i have a row in order table also order-id in orderdetail

Comment: And I assume `order-id` isn't the primary key in `orderdetail` table?

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class order extends Model
{
    //
}

Comment: order_id isn't primery in my orderdetail tbl

Comment: See my edit; `findOrFail()` tries to find a record based off of the primary key set in the Model (default of id), so if you're passing an `orderId` as `$id`, you need your query to check that instead.